# Visual Studio 2022 Source Control Plugins

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to specify a source control plugin on the startup command line for the Visual Studio 2022 IDE?

We are transitioning from TFS to Git. Switching source control plugins in the IDE is not simple when we have to work on projects from both the old and new source control systems every day.

Having different instances of the visual studio IDE configured for different source control systems will reduce developer churn. Can this be done?

Tried to manually switch plugins during a working session and the IDE loses track of source control bindings.